# Handling unknown parameters in httprequest

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net

If extra/unknown parameters are passed in via the Header or request body , I want to return a 400. I am using Newtonsoft to do the serialization. I have set the MissingMemberHandling to MissingMemberHandling.Error.

I am using the [FromHeader] and [FromBody] to serialize the parameters in my API. If I send extra parameters in the requestBody, I do get an error. However, if I pass in extra paramters in the Header, the extra parameters are ignored.

In startup.cs i have

```
  services.AddControllers()
                  .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                  {
                      options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                      options.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;                     
                  })
```

My controller API is as follows

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<Response>> TestAPI([FromRoute][FromHeader] RequestHeader header, RequestBody body)
    {..
}

public class RequestHeader
{
   
    [FromHeader(Name = "x-sessionId")]
    public string SessionId {get; set;}
}

public class RequestBody 
{
 [FromBody(Id= "id")]
    public string Id{get;set;}
}
```

If i pass in anything other than the id in the body, Newtonsoft does return an error. If i pass in additional parameters in the header, those parameters are ignored.

Why does the MissingMemberHandling not work with headers?  Also, how do I check if there are extra parameters in the header or query and return an error? I am looking for a generic solution that will work across all my APIs

Comment: When you bind value from header, It will bind successfully without showing any error message? May be you can post an issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed "acceptable headers" you can create a CORS Policy that will sort of do that for you, returning errors to the UI if some weird headers are sent. You can tweak it to be really strict or more or less loose depending on your needs.

```
return services
            .AddCors(x => x
                .AddPolicy("YourPolicyName", policy => policy
                    .WithHeaders(new[] { "MyHeader" })
                    .WithExposedHeaders(new[] { "MyHeader" })));
```

Then remember to call it on `UseCors(policyName)` to activate the policy.

You can dynamically set the acceptable headers by fetching them from the appsettings.json file as well.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately not all my APIs have the same headers

Comment: Extract to a package and put them all there. That's configurable. Each application has a subset of headers, right? You can have them on appsettings and startup like that using CORS policies or you can create a package that handles all headers at once and you can fetch/tryfetch them at will. You can have a middleware that can register known headers at startup using a redis/mongo/blob or something persistent.